# problem while running php artisan route:list with jwt installed

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I've followed this tutorial 
https://tutsforweb.com/restful-api-in-laravel-56-using-jwt-authentication/
and it's working fine,
but when i try to run

> > php artisan route:list

i get this error ,

```
  Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException  : The token could not be parsed from the request

  at F:\My_Projects\Laravel\api-laravel-jwt\vendor\tymon\jwt-auth\src\JWT.php:185
    181|      */
    182|     public function parseToken()
    183|     {
    184|         if (! $token = $this->parser->parseToken()) {
  > 185|             throw new JWTException('The token could not be parsed from the request');
    186|         }
    187|
    188|         return $this->setToken($token);
    189|     }

  Exception trace:

  1   Tymon\JWTAuth\JWT::parseToken()
      F:\My_Projects\Laravel\api-laravel-jwt\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php:223

  2   Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic("parseToken", [])
      F:\My_Projects\Laravel\api-laravel-jwt\app\Http\Controllers\ProductController.php:14

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

and i've been trying to get around it, but couldn't succeed, any help?

This is a github Repo with my code:-

https://github.com/Imohamedgabr/laravel-5.7-jwt-starter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the product controller, in this part:-

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
}
```

it calls the parse token, that's why it goes to the jwt auth parse token and fails there.
so while there's no authenticated user provided, it fails.
hope this helps.